# Searching a file for a string then printing with additional an additional string and formatting - awk, sed or python?

Tags: awk, sed

Thank you for taking the time to look at my issue. I am relatively new to trying to use awk and sed as I am trying to write a script search for a specific string in a line, then print text that appears afterwards in a specific format with a specific string

My file looks like this

```
search_string1 cat mouse fish
search_string2 cat mouse fish
notmysearchstring cat mouse fish
search_string3 cat mouse fish
```

What I would like is to be able create a new file with it in such a way that a specific string appears lets call "dog":

```
search_string1 cat dog dog
search_string1 dog mouse dog
search_string1 dog dog fish
search_string2 cat dog dog
search_string2 dog mouse dog
search_string2 dog dog fish
search_string3 cat dog dog
search_string3 dog mouse dog
search_string3 dog dog fish
```

I have tried looking at using awk and sed but the formatting and insertion of the string part of the function are difficult to understand.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I use `ag` for all my searchs stuffs now: very fast! https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with awk:

```
$ awk -v v="dog" \
  '!/notmysearchstring/{        # Avoid non wanted pattern
      l=$0                      # Store the current line
      split($0,a)               # Get all line fields into an array
      for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){       # Loop through the fields (avoid the 1st one)
         for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){    # Loop through the fields (avoid the 1st one)
            $j=v                # Set all elements to the wanted string
         };
         $i=a[i]                # Override with the current field
      print                     # Display the result
      $0=l                      # Restore the line 
   }
}' file
search_string1 cat dog dog
search_string1 dog mouse dog
search_string1 dog dog fish
search_string2 cat dog dog
search_string2 dog mouse dog
search_string2 dog dog fish
search_string3 cat dog dog
search_string3 dog mouse dog
search_string3 dog dog fish
```

Comment: Thankyou! That has worked perfectly, it was the loop counter I couldn't get right! +1

Comment: @AlexMorritt you accepted the first answer you got. You may have got lucky and that first answer was the best possible answer or there may be better answers that you'll now not get a chance to consider since people are no longer reading your question since you accepted an answer. Just something to think about for if/when you ask your next question...